# Java NIO SSL - SSLEngine Session reuse

Tags: java, ssl, java-8, nio, jsse

I am implementing client and server part using Java 8 NIO and SSL.
I have some doubts on creating SSLEngine.

There is one method in SSLContext

```
public final SSLEngine createSSLEngine(String peerHost,
                                   int peerPort)
```

> Applications using this factory method are providing hints for an internal session reuse strategy.

While creating the SSLEngine at client side, I have to give server's ip and port.
But while creating SSLEngine at server side, which IP and port I should give ?

As per RFC2246, the client has to send "Session ID" in ClientHello Message, and Server will check its "Session Cache" for its match.
How would I say to server's SSLEngine to enable "Session cache" ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> While creating the SSLEngine at client side, I have to give server's ip and port. But while creating SSLEngine at server side, which IP and port I should give ?

The client's.

> As per RFC2246, the client has to send "Session ID" in ClientHello Message, and Server will check its "Session Cache" for its match. How would I say to server's SSLEngine to enable "Session cache"?

It's on by default, as long as the server-side `SSLEngine` knows the client IP:port.